# Click on a button when parsing a site

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to parse a table, for example, from this page (or any other historical snapshot):
https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/20160228/

The following code successfully parses the first 200 rows of this table.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response_date = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/20160228/')
pastebin_url_date = response_date.text
soup_get_date = BeautifulSoup(pastebin_url_date, 'lxml')

table = soup_get_date.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "cmc-table__table-wrapper-outer"})[2]
table_body = table.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    ...
```

**The problem is** that there are 513 rows there, and I don't know how to click on the "Load More" buttons while there are such buttons. How to press button "Load More" while it is there?

On this page, the button "Load More" has to pressed 2 times (on others, maybe more, maybe less).

Answer (score 2):

Those pages are loaded dynamically and there's really no "physical" way to *click on a button* with `bs4`.

However, there's an API you can query and loop over the pages to get more data.

**NOTE:** I'm using a limit to the pages with `for page in all_pages[:3]`; to get all the data just remove `[:3]` to make it look this `for page in all pages:`.

Here's how:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests

query_string = [
    ('start', '1'),
    ('limit', '100'),
    ('sortBy', 'market_cap'),
    ('sortType', 'desc'),
    ('convert', 'USD'),
    ('cryptoType', 'all'),
    ('tagType', 'all'),
]

base = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/cryptocurrency/listing?"
response = requests.get(f"{base}{urlencode(query_string)}").json()
last_page = (int(response["data"]["totalCount"]) // 100) + 1
all_pages = [1 if i == 0 else (i * 100) + 1 for i in range(1, last_page)]
print(f"There are {len(all_pages)} pages.")

results = []
for page in all_pages[:3]:
    query_string = [
        ('start', str(page)),
        ('limit', '100'),
        ('sortBy', 'market_cap'),
        ('sortType', 'desc'),
        ('convert', 'USD'),
        ('cryptoType', 'all'),
        ('tagType', 'all'),
    ]
    response = requests.get(f"{base}{urlencode(query_string)}").json()
    results.extend([
        [
            currency["name"],
            round(currency["quotes"][0]["price"], 4),
        ]
        for currency in response["data"]["cryptoCurrencyList"]
    ])

print("{:<30}{:>10}".format(*["Currency", "Value"]))
print("\n".join("{:<30}{:>10}".format(*item) for item in results))
```

Output:

```
There are 48 pages.
Currency                           Value
Bitcoin                       49797.3732
Ethereum                       2223.4234
Binance Coin                    496.2642
Tether                            1.0001
XRP                               1.0477
Cardano                            1.113
Dogecoin                          0.2712
Polkadot                         29.6033
Uniswap                          30.6648
Litecoin                        225.2603
Bitcoin Cash                    774.4016
Chainlink                        31.6194
VeChain                           0.1777
Solana                           42.2906
USD Coin                          0.9999
Stellar                           0.4273
Filecoin                        133.4884
THETA                             8.8757
Wrapped Bitcoin                49938.205
TRON                              0.1042
Binance USD                       0.9998
Monero                          388.1286
Terra                            16.4256
Neo                              80.8837
Klaytn                             2.113
EOS                                5.202
IOTA                              1.6668
PancakeSwap                      28.0534
Bitcoin SV                      238.5014
BitTorrent                        0.0067
FTX Token                        45.5833
Crypto.com Coin                   0.1693
Aave                            322.3405
Cosmos                           18.6716
Maker                          3835.4303
Dai                               1.0003
Tezos                             4.5509
Ethereum Classic                 29.5024
Algorand                          1.1523
Huobi Token                      17.2733
Avalanche                        22.1258
Compound                         549.279
Bitcoin BEP2                  49741.0943
Dash                            260.2305

and a lot more ...
```

Comment: it seems there was a tool like Silenium to push buttons.

api yes, but there's historical data only for money that I don't have :)

Comment: Specify, please, where did you find the /v3/ API?
I constantly only find /v1/*/ API, where under * can be, for example, cryptocurrency (/v1/cryptocurrency/)